# Corrupt object key in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a file in an S3 bucket that is corrupt and I am unable to delete it. I get the following error from console:

[image]
[image]

Not sure how to get rid of that file. Trying to move throws the following error:

```
$ aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/corrup\†\&\#x1c\;o.html s3://<bucket>/test/corr.html
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "corrup†&#x1c;o.html" does not exist
```

Update:
`aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket <bucket name> --debug`

```
2019-03-10 11:49:00,781 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/parsers.py", line 432, in _parse_xml_string_to_dom
parser.feed(xml_string
File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 2, column 129326
```

Comment: The object isn't "corrupt" -- its key simply contains one or more charaters that the tools are handling incorrectly due to encoding bugs.  Start with `aws s3api list-objects` to try to find the actual characters/bytes making up the object key.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I did the `list-objects` but it does not show the file from the image above. It showed other weird files and I was able to delete those objects.

Comment: Interesting. The ETag of the weird file shown matches the one from the console. Yet, if I delete it, it creates a new entry in the console with the delete marker but the original object is still there.

Comment: Your bucket has versioning enabled.  Use `aws s3api list-object-versions` to see both current and previous versions.  Deleting an object in a versioned bucket only creates a delete marker.  Deleting a specific object *version* (by specifying both the object key *and* a specific version-id) actually removes the object version completely.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Michael-sqlbot. I did the `aws s3api list-object-versions` but still cannot delete the file. `$ aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket <bucketname>` 
Output:
`Unable to parse response (reference to invalid character number: line 2, column 129326), invalid XML received:`

Comment: Neat error.  I would definitely call that a bug -- in either S3's API or perhaps the cli's XML parser -- if an object can actually be created whose value in a bucket's object listing cannot be parsed.  How did you originally create the file?  In the console, or using one of the SDKs?  (Which one?)  Does the error message actually include the faulty XML?  Or, can you capture it if you add the `--debug` option to the cli?

Comment: Initially, I used the `aws cp` to copy files to S3 bucket.

Comment: Added some of the output up there...not sure how to add multi-line output in a comment. Formatting was all weird. :)